# selecting dynamic checkbox by name...jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap table with checkboxes. The html is rendered as follows:

```
<td class="bs-checkbox">
 <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
 </td>
<td class="bs-checkbox">
 <input data-index="1" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
 </td>
```

When a user checks one of the boxes, i want an event fired to trap it. This is how i'm trying to do so, with no avail:

```
     $('table').on('click', 'input[name=btSelectItem]', function (index, obj){
    alert(obj);
});
```

The data is coming from an ajax call, so its dynamic. How do i fire my code when a user clicks on one of the checkboxes? Thanks

Comment: If `table` is dynamic too then you should set another element to start with.

Comment: what is obj? what are you trying to access there?

Comment: @Chaitanya Gadkari - obj is just dummy data. When i click a checkbox, i would expect an alert box to popup. it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

You are going right way, as u_mulder suggested, if table is dynamic too, use another element, maybe document

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[name=btSelectItem]', function (){
    alert($(this).attr('data-index')); // I suppose this is index you needed, i am not sure of obj
});
```

Comment: I have to be doing something wrong. This code is straight forward and should work. Thanks

Comment: I suppose just the variables passed to function, i am not sure how to pass variable exactly... But you capture it in `function (event)` and access data by `event.Data`